# What is wrong with my JPA Criteria API code (taken from JEE6 Tutorial)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

This is my code, which I can't even compile:

```
/**
 * Find a project that has NO employee assigned yet.
 */
public Project findEmptyProject() {
  // getting criteria builder
  CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  // gathering meta information about left-joined entity
  Metamodel m = this.em.getMetamodel();
  EntityType<Employee> Employee_ = m.entity(Employee.class);
  // creating query
  CriteriaQuery<Project> cq = cb.createQuery(Project.class);
  // setting query root for the query
  Root<Project> project = cq.from(Project.class);
  // left-joining with another employees
  Join<Employee, Project> projects = project.join(
    Employee_.project, 
    JoinType.LEFT
  );
  // instructing the query to select only projects
  // where we have NO employees
  cq.select(project).where(Employee_.id.isNull());
  // fetching real data from the database
  return this.em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
}
```

My model classes are:

```
public class Employee {
  @Id private Integer id;
  @ManyToOne private Project project;
  private String name;
}

public class Project {
  @Id private Integer id;
  private String name;
}
```

Compiler says (and I would say the same being a compiler):

```
Finder.java: cannot find symbol: variable project
location: interface javax.persistence.metamodel.EntityType<com.XXX.Employee>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `Employee_.project` syntax, `Employee_` must be an *autogenerated metamodel class*, not an `EntityType` obtained via `Metamodel.entity()`.

[Hibernate JPA 2 Metamodel Generator manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/1.0/reference/en-US/html_single/) explains how to configure generation of these classes in Hibernate.

Comment: But this is what I've taken from tutorial (http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html). The tutorial is wrong?

Comment: @Vincenzo: It's astonishing, but the tutorial is wrong. Authors of tutorial confused dynamic metamodel (obtained via `getMetamodel()`) with static metamodel (generated by processing tools). Only static metamodel can be used to access properties such as `Employee_.project`. By the way, you query is also wrong - this kind of query would require `RIGHT JOIN` in JPQL, but Criteria API doesn't support right joins. You can rewrite it with subquery and `NOT EXISTS`.